# Docker/Ruby - creating Docker service results in "rails new APP_PATH [options]" and services exiting with code 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I'm new to Ruby and a little new to Docker. I looked on here for an answer to this beforehand but did not see my issue.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:3.2.1-alpine 
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /rails
RUN apk update && \
  apk add --no-cache build-base nodejs postgresql-client yarn
# Install Gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /rails/
RUN bundle install --jobs=3 --retry=3
# Install npm packages
COPY package.json yarn.lock /app/
# Create Rails application
RUN rails new app -j esbuild --force --database=postgresql --css=bootstrap --skip-git

COPY . .

# Configure the main process to run when running the image
CMD ["rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

And my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
        - .:/rails
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
```

I'm trying to create a containerized Ruby application with Docker. In my terminal, when I type `docker compose up --build`, I get the below message in my console

```
Attaching to ruby-on-rails-boilerplate-app-1, ruby-on-rails-boilerplate-db-1
ruby-on-rails-boilerplate-app-1  | Usage:
ruby-on-rails-boilerplate-app-1  |   rails new APP_PATH [options]
ruby-on-rails-boilerplate-app-1  |
ruby-on-rails-boilerplate-app-1  | Options:
```

Etc. It would seem like i'm not in the right directory, but I can't find a way to verify that. What's my issue? What did I miss? If you need more information, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Docker image you are:

1. Creating a directory `/rails`
2. Copying your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` into `/rails`
3. Running `bundle install` from `/rails`
4. Running `rails new app` from the directory `/rails`, thus attempting to create a *new* directory named `/rails/app` and attempting to place a *new* Rails app in that directory
5. Copying `.` (and all its files and folders) into `/rails`

The best case scenario is that in the end you would have:

- `/rails/<your actual Rails app>`
- `/rails/app/<a new Rails app>`

That is most likely not what you're intending to do. I'm having a hard time imagining why you would want to create a new Rails app from scratch as part of creating your Docker image which is why I believe this is not intended.

Most likely you are intending to copy the Rails app that you already have locally on disk into your Docker image and have your Docker container start *that* Rails app. If that's the case then you should remove the following line so that you don't attempt to create a new app in `/rails/app`:

```
# Create Rails application
RUN rails new app -j esbuild --force --database=postgresql --css=bootstrap --skip-git
```

Additionally, you should carefully review this line:

```
COPY package.json yarn.lock /app/
```

You are copying these files to `/app` which is outside of `/rails`. I assume that your local directory structure has `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` and `package.json` and `yarn.lock` all in the same directory and that you intend for them to be in the same directory inside your Docker image. If that is the case then you need to change `/app/` to `./` so that they are copied to `/rails` instead.

And finally, this line:

```
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /rails/
```

Can be reduced to:

```
COPY Gemfile* ./
```

Because `./` will reference the path relative to `WORKDIR`, in your case `/rails`, so specifying `/rails/` is an unnecessary redundancy.

I recommend that you test building your Docker image outside of Docker Compose. You can do this with:

```bash
docker build . -t rails
```

Watch the output to confirm that the image builds successfully. Once it has built you can run a temporary container from the image with the following command:

```bash
docker run -it --rm rails sh
```

This will drop you into a shell in your container and allow you to use, for example, `ls` to inspect the directory structure and make sure the image looks the way you expect it to look. You can then `exit` once you're sure it's built correctly and run it with Docker Compose.

Comment: I had a misunderstanding about Docker that you corrected. Thank you.